# How do I use a vue.js component library when building a web component

Tags: vue.js, web-component, quasar-framework

I need to create a web component that will be used as an embeddable widget in various sites.
For this, I'm following the Vue.js docs for using the web component build target of vue-cli.

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-element MyElement.vue
```

This command creates a standalone web component from the `MyElement` vue.js component. So far everything works as expected.

My first problem comes from different entry points for the web component and for the "normal" build. For the normal build, we have a `main.js` file which loads Vue, registers global plugins with `Vue.use(plugin)` and creates a new Vue instance. When using the `wc` target, the entry point is just an element, so there are no options to register global plugins with `Vue.use()` which needs to be run before creating the Vue instance.

So my first question: **How do I load plugins with `Vue.use()` when building a web component?**

My 2nd question: I use a component library for Vue, like Quasar. (or any other) But I get strange errors when using the built web components, which I don't get when running a "normal" build. Is there some particular reason that certain component libraries wouldn't work for a `wc` target? If so, what is it? How can I get around it? Are there any particular component libraries which support web components?